# I can't put any image in electron app, background-image doesn't work, img scr doesn't work, what may i do? Very strange

Tags: electron

I can't put any image in electron app, background-image don't work, img scr don't work, canvas.drawImage don't work what may i do?
Obvious code:

```
<img src="file://bg.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"> 
...
body{ background-image: url('file:///bg.jpg') 50px 50px repeat; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of the `image` is **wrong**.

You can either user `Absolute Path` or `Relative Path` - [Absolute V/s Relative Path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2005079/11926970)

> ## Use Relative Path as they are not bound to a base URL

Now coming back to your problem, `file://bg.jpg` is not a valid path.

As you have given the structure of your project let us consider that you wanted the `background image` and `<img />` in file **index.html** and image **bg.jpg** are both in the same directory.

Which mean if your `files structure` is like this

**project_folder**
   |
  index.html
   |   main.js
   |   bg.jpg

Then instead of `file://bg.jpg` use `bg.jpg`.

Thus you code become like

```
<img src="bg.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"> 
...
body{ background-image: url('bg.jpg') 50px 50px repeat; }
```

> ## **NOTE:** Only valid if both HTML file and image are in the same directory

If **not** then you have to use a `relative` path to access the image

Comment: Can you share the file structure of your project and is there any error in console?

Comment: texturator:
--index.js
--script.js
--css.css
--mainWindow.html
--bg.jpg

Comment: files in same folder